How to install package in remote interpreter in Pycharm + Poetry?
I have a FastAPI + Celery + Pytest app with next structure:

Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.11 as normal

WORKDIR /portal-podrjadchika

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./
COPY ./src .

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gcc libc6-dev wget libpq-dev unzip && apt-get clean && pip install poetry==1.8.3

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && poetry install

docker-compose.yaml:
version: '3.11'

services:
  build: &build
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/portal-podrjadchika
#      - ./poetry.lock:/portal-podrjadchika/poetry.lock
#      - ./pyproject.toml:/portal-podrjadchika/pyproject.toml

  fastapi-app:
    <<: *build
    env_file:
      - app.env
    command: bash -c "uvicorn main.app:fastapi_app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db

  celery:
    <<: *build
    env_file:
      - app.env
    command: bash -c "celery -A main.celery:celery_app worker"
    depends_on:
      - redis

  flower:
    <<: *build
    env_file:
      - app.env
    command: bash -c "celery -A main.celery:celery_app flower"
    depends_on:
      - celery
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"

  tests:
    <<: *build
    stdin_open: true
    env_file:
      - tests.env

  db:
    image: postgres:14.7-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_portal_podrjadchika_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=portal_podrjadchika
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=portal_podrjadchika
      - POSTGRES_DB=portal-podrjadchika
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  redis:
    image: redis:7.4.1-alpine3.20
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"

volumes:
  postgres_portal_podrjadchika_data:

services in Pycharm:

and remote interpreter:

For now I'm trying to figure out how to install packages? I mean there are remote interpreter for only fastapi-app and package should be installed in each container (celery, flower, fastapi-app and tests). Also pyproject.yaml and poetry.lock should be updated when package installed... How could I do that?
